# PHP + jquery Timer not woring with server time

Tags: php, jquery

i have one online exam portal and each exam is time basis so i have to display the time of the exam as countdown on the page.
My issue is that if i will change my system/PC/laptop time the countdown is also changed. for example. if the exam duration is 10min and after the starting the exam if i change my laptop time to 1hr back then my timer is also changed to 1hr and 10min.
Here below i mentioned my code

```
function get15dayFromNow() {
    var t = $('#ex_time').val();
    return t;
}
$clock.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
}).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    alert("Exam Time Complete");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a server-side time

Comment: Where is your PHP code? And are you hosting your site on a remote server or on your local machine?

Comment: An easy way is that you save the start/end time in a database and the JavaScript code is just to display the time with a countdown. If you are using a database you can check the time when the user submits the exam or you can check the time with ajax.

Comment: hi. i don't want to save end time. i just want to display the timer. if time complete then exam complete. this  var t = $('#ex_time').val(); will return the end time of the exam.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your code is you are getting the Time from the client's side, why dont you modify your code and get time from the server?, you can make an AJAX call to a simple API that gives out the difference between the current (server) time and the time the test finishes.

The Javascript (JQuery) part will only display the countdown based on the server's result. This way you can always have reliable and consistent countdown value that is independent of the client's clock.

Making an AJAX call in jquery is very simple incase you are not sure how to do it here is a simple sinppet below

```
$.ajax({ 
        type:    'POST', 
        url:     '/getCountDownValue',
        data:    { testID:1 },
        success: function (data) { 
                    //Do something awesome
                 },
                 error: function(){
                    //Handle your errors
                 }
});
```

You can find more details on the documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: hi.  var t = $('#ex_time').val(); will return the end time. instead of ajax call i have stored the end time on hidden field. is it right way to do ?

Comment: This will also work, as long as you will validate the time values on the server side upon submission of your exam, the rule of thumb for your situation is to not trust that the client will always return the correct value

Comment: but my issue is that client change its laptop local time and my timer is also updated